# in java 6 we have set the application server perm gen size as 2GB. what is the equivalent in java 8 meta space

Tags: java, permgen, metaspace

Application server : `Jboss EAP 6`
We are trying to migrate our application from Java 6 to Java 8.
In java 6 - perm gen size is 2 GB.
What is the perm gen equivalent(Meta space) value in Java 8.
I set

```
-XX:MetaspaceSize=2g
```

Is this equivalent to min permgen 2gb in Java 6?

Comment: Wow, what application requires 2GB perm gen space?

Comment: It is insurance Application. concurrently 1000+ users accessing our application.

Answer (score 0):

- `-XX:MetaspaceSize` corresponds to `-XX:PermSize` and sets the initial size of the Metaspace area.
- `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` corresponds to `-XX:MaxPermSize` and sets the maximum size. By default, there is no upper limit for Metaspace - it auto increases up to what the underlying OS can deliver. PermGen always has an upper limit, which on most JMVs defaults to 64 MB.

(There is also `-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio` and `-XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio`)